# "Ionic Cordova run android" got launch success message, but the app isn't launching on the phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Some days ago I've updated my phone from Android 7.1.1 to Android 8.1 Oreo. After that update, when I try to run the command "ionic cordova run android" or "ionic cordova run android -l", the cmd console shows the message:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 15s 47 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 45 up-to-date Built the following apk(s):
        D:\Plural Systems\Painel do Gestor\siematecapp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Jer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65 No target specified, deploying to device '0044699831'.

none 

Skipping build... Built the following apk(s):
        D:\Plural Systems\Painel do Gestor\siematecapp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Using apk: D:\Plural Systems\Painel do Gestor\siematecapp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Package name: br.doctorvet.app 

LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

But after this message, the app didn't open on Android.

I've already tried removing the android platform and add the platform again; update the cordova-plugin-webview from 1.2 to 2.0, remove and then add the android platform; disable USB debugging, revoke USB debugging authorizations, enable/disable "Verify apps over USB; I've created a new ionic blank project and run the command, it worked,  but only for the first time; I tried to clone the project from git and install the project, add android platform but the same problem occurs.

I don't know why it is happening. It started after I've updated my Android version to 8.1 and before that, everything was working fine.

What could be causing this?

My `IONIC INFO`

cli packages: (C:\Users\Jer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.11.2
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

My `IONIC REQUIREMENTS`

```
Android Studio project detected


Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-27,android-26,android-25
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.4\bin\gradle
```

Comment: Ionic build android it gives you errors?

Comment: No, any errors. I'm not understanding what is going on

Comment: If you want the livereload the command is ionic run android —device -lc and the device and the pc it has to be both on the same WiFi network

Comment: Check also with adb devices command  if you device appear as device on the right

Comment: I am facing this issue now. Please help me if this was fixed.

Comment: The problem was the guest user. I had a guest user enabled and everything that I installed under ionic commands in the main user was installed in the guest user, but when I run the command for the second time, the application on guest was updated. So every time I run some ionic command, I need to uninstall the application on guest user before run ionic cordova run-build android.

Comment: Thank you @jraspante, your last comment is exactly the problem I'm facing right now! I have shelter installed. Maybe you can add this as accepted answer, so other users can see this faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the guest user. I had a guest user enabled and everything that I installed under ionic commands in the main user was installed in the guest user, but when I run the command for the second time, the application on guest was updated. So every time I run some ionic command, I need to uninstall the application on guest user before run ionic cordova run-build android.

Answer (score 0):

the `run` command would be:

```
ionic cordova run android -lc
```

while you need to add one of these:

```
--device    Deploy Cordova build to a device
--target    Deploy Cordova build to a device (use --list to see all)
```

because it complains ...

> *no target specified*

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use these commands that you suggested, but it still not working.